# Show values from DB in specifc HTML table cell

Tags: php, loops, html-table

I am trying to get a table view from DB values in a specific pattern.
It should look like this:
[Plan View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeD5I.png)

In the DB I have added row/col values to assign the "cell names" to a specific cell:

[DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fEHU.png)

Using this code:

```
$maxrow = getResult($pdo, "SELECT MAX(row) AS maxrow FROM stalls")["maxrow"];
$maxcol = getResult($pdo, "SELECT MAX(col) AS maxcol FROM stalls")["maxcol"];

$data = $pdo->query("SELECT row, col, number FROM stalls ORDER BY row ASC, col ASC")->fetchAll();

echo'<table style="width:100%;">';
foreach ($data as $entry) 
{
    if($entry['row'] > 0)
    {
        for($r=0;$r<=$maxrow;$r++)
        {
            if($r == $entry['row'])
            {
                echo '<tr style="border: 1px solid black;">';

                    for($c=1;$c<=$maxcol;$c++)
                    {
                        if($c == $entry['col'])
                        {
                            echo    '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">row: '. $r . ' - col: ' . $c . ' - value: ' . $entry['number'] .'</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo    '<td style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>';
                        }
                    }
                    
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

I can only get this view:

[Shifted rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2yHC.png)

How would I get the values of "row 1" to be shown in row 1, without the "shift"?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Store your data into a multidimensional array first, use the row number as key on the first level, and the column number on the second. Then you can relatively easy create your table using two nested `for` loops, and while doing so you just pick the data for the current row and column out of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like - note this is untested code:

```
$maxrow = getResult($pdo, "SELECT MAX(row) AS maxrow FROM stalls")["maxrow"];
$maxcol = getResult($pdo, "SELECT MAX(col) AS maxcol FROM stalls")["maxcol"];

$oldRow = 0;    // init row counter
$arr = array_fill( 0, $maxcol, "&nbsp;" );
$tmp = "";

echo'<table style="width:100%;">';
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    // get the data
    $row = $entry['row'];
    $col = $entry['col'];
    $nbr = $entry['number'];
    // is the row number different and not the first entry
    if( $oldRow != $entry['row'] && $oldRow != 0 ) {
        //--- convert to html type string
        $tmp = implode( "</td><td>", $arr );
        //--- show html
        echo'<tr><td>".$tmp."</td></tr>";
        //--- reset temp values
        $arr = array_fill( 0, $maxcol, "&nbsp;" );
        $oldRow = $entry['row']; // set new row number
    }
    $arr[$row][$col] = $nbr;
}
//--- convert to html type string for last entry processed
$tmp = implode( "</td><td>", $arr );
//--- show html
echo'<tr><td>".$tmp."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: jeff, thank you for your comment! unfortunately this did not bring up the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, not very nice, but it works for me...

```
// get max rows
$maxrow = getResult($pdo, "SELECT MAX(row) AS maxrow FROM stalls")["maxrow"];
// get max cols
$maxcol = getResult($pdo, "SELECT MAX(col) AS maxcol FROM stalls")["maxcol"];
// get rows and number of cols in row
$rowmeta = $pdo->query("SELECT row, COUNT(*) as count FROM stalls WHERE row <> 0 GROUP BY row ORDER BY row ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// get rest of stuff
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT row, col, number FROM stalls ORDER BY row ASC, col ASC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo'<table style="table-layout: fixed; width:100%;">';
// iterate trough rows from meta
foreach($rowmeta as $rowmeta_row) 
{
    echo '<tr style="width: calc(100%/'.$maxcol.');border: 1px solid black;">';
    // get data part
    foreach($data as $d) 
    {
        // check if we're still in same row as data
        if($rowmeta_row["row"] == $d['row'])
        {       
            // move left trough cols
            for($c=1;$c<=$maxcol;$c++)
            {
                // check if we're in the right col and it is not an isle
                if($c == $d['col'] && $d['number'] != 'isle')
                {
                    echo    '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">row: '. $d['row'] . ' - col: ' . $d['col'] . ' - value: ' . $d['number'] .'</td>';
                }
                // still in right col, but isle
                if($c == $d['col'] && $d['number'] == 'isle')
                {
                    echo    '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">leer</td>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```